# Would Sean Raymond's "Ultimate Solar System" Work in This Particular System?

Tags: science-based, orbital-mechanics, stars, solar-system

[image]

Presented here is a system in which a binary of orange dwarves orbits a binary of yellow dwarves.  Each yellow dwarf is 105% as wide, 110% as massive and 126% as bright as our sun.  Each orange dwarf is 85% as wide, 78% as massive and only 40% as bright as our sun.  It is in the orange dwarf binary that we see a solar system that looks similar to one of Sean Raymond's projections of an "ultimate solar system":

[image]

However, the system that this question is centered on has some differences:

1. Raymond's worlds vary between 50 and 200% the size of Earth, whereas the worlds I'm aiming for variances between 95% the diameter and 82% the mass (like Venus) and 230% the diameter and 700% the mass (like [Lyr](http://www.worlddreambank.org/L/LYR.HTM).)
2. Raymond chose a red dwarf for the worlds to orbit, whereas I'm picking a binary of orange dwarves.  It could help widen the habitable zone.

In this system, "summer" is where all four suns from both binaries are in the sky, whereas "winter" has only the two orange dwarves in the sky.

Using the information provided above, the question raises--**will the "ultimate solar system" work in such conditions as these?**

Comment: .  Do you mean: have all the planets in the picture, but orbiting a red binary in a 4 star system?  Does the Ultimate Solar system have all of the planets shown or are those options, of which one or two are in the system?

Comment: The differences are all in the post.

Comment: Sorry, but like @Willk I'm not entirely certain of what you mean.  Do you mean that the planets are orbiting the barycentre of the paired orange dwarfs?  With the entire orange-dwarfs-and-planets "system" orbiting the barycentre of the four stars combined?  If that is the case, then we need to solve a 5+ body problem to work out the habitable zone width?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Lagrange points around a binary are not at all stable on astronomical timespans.
Putting binary planets in a lagrange point is already asking for trouble even with one massive central star. It works, barely, but the least little perturbation tends to get amplified over time, leading to Pinball.

Illumination wise, and thus for habitable zones, your system works just fine.